# How to not exist on another table

Tags: php, mysql

How to not exist on another table on this two table?

`Users table`
[image]

`User_relationships table`

[image]

and this is my current query

```
"SELECT * FROM `users` 
WHERE CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) LIKE '%' . $name . '%' 
    AND (`role_id` = 6 OR `role_id` = 4)
ORDER BY `first_name` asc limit 15"
```

and I want to add on query where `guardian_id(user_id)` not exist on the `user_relationships` table

**UPDATE 1**

```
select * from `users` 
    where not exists 
            (select 1 from `user_relationships` 
             inner join `users` on `user_relationships`.`guardian_id` = `users`.`id` 
             where `user_relationships`.`student_id` = 422)
```

I tried this and still returns me zero result.

I only have var `name = ?` and `student_id = ?`

Comment: Would you please add your expected output?

Comment: try this **SELECT u.* FROM users u 
INNER JOIN User_relationships ur ON ur.guardian_id != u.id 
WHERE CONCAT(u.first_name," ", u.last_name) LIKE '%' . $name . '%' AND (u.role_id= 6 u.orrole_id= 4) order by u.first_name ASC LIMIT 15**  we are **using join** here and **checking the user id of user's table and guarding id from User_relationships table should not be the same** .. let me know if it works or any issue.

Comment: I update my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use "NOT IN" query function with 'DISTINCT'.

following may help you.

```
select * from users where CONCAT(first_name, " ", last_name) LIKE '%' . $name . '%' and (role_id= 6 or role_id= 4) and (id NOT IN (select DISTINCT guardian_id from User_relationships where student_id = $student_id)) order by first_name ASC limit 15
```

Let me know if you still need some changes.

Comment: Check new query, i Keep Distinct as is coz i think you may have one guardian connect with many student. if not you can take it out as well.